# Angular Material : need additional interaction to trigger rendering

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm facing a strange behaviour with angular material: some components need an additional event (like click or mouse movement on the div of interest) to trigger the actual rendering.
For example, with the mat-table, when it loads new rows, some empty rows are still displayed and as soon as I scroll down or click one of them, they disappear.
Another example is with the dialog: when I click outside the border, nothing happend, but if I click again or scroll, it disappear.
Here's my angular-cli version.
Thanks

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.14
Node: 13.0.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.14
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.14
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.14
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.14
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.14
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.14
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.14
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.14
@schematics/angular               8.3.14
@schematics/update                0.803.14
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.41.2
```

First of all, thanks for the answers.
I noticed that all the problems are linked to the mat Table: the dialog that cause problems is triggered from a button inside the table and if
I move it outside, it works properly.
The component of the table are the following:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    
    dataSource : MyTableSource;
    @ViewChild(MatTable, {static:true}) table: MatTable<any>;
    dtOptions: any = { 
            displayedColumns : [ 'colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD'],
            search : { value : "" } ,
            order : { name : 'values' , asc : true },
            subset : [] , 
            pageSize : 10,
            pageIndex : 0,
            draw : 0 , 
            recordsTotal : 0, 
            recordsFiltered : 0};

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
            private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,private trackService: TracksService) {
    };
   ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new KmerTableSource(this.trackService);
   }
   refreshTable(event?:any){
        if ( event){
            if ( event.pageSize){
                this.dtOptions.pageSize=event.pageSize;
                this.dtOptions.pageIndex=event.pageIndex;
            }
            if (event.active){
                this.dtOptions.order.name = event.active;
                this.dtOptions.order.asc = event.direction == "asc";
            }
        }
        
        this.dataSource.loadData(this.dtOptions);
    }
    
}
```

The html

```
<table mat-table matSort (matSortChange)="refreshTable($event)" [dataSource]="dataSource" >
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="importance">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>Col A</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.A}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="kmer">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>Col B</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.B}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
                            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header>Col C</th>
                            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.C}}</td>
                        </ng-container>
                        
                        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="dtOptions.displayedColumns;sticky : true;"></tr>
                        <tr mat-row cdk-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: dtOptions.displayedColumns"></tr>
                    </table>
```

The data source

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class MyTableSource implements DataSource<DataPoint> {
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<DataPoint[]>([]);
    
  constructor(private trackService :TracksService ) { }

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<DataPoint[]> {
      return this.dataSubject.asObservable();
  }

  disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
      this.dataSubject.complete();
  }
  
  loadData(request : any) {
      this.trackService.getDataTable(request).pipe(
              catchError(()=>of([])),
      ).subscribe(response => {
          this.dataSubject.next(response);
       });
  }
  
}
```

The track service ( I'm using electron )

```
@Injectable( {
    providedIn: 'root'
} )


export class TracksService {
    protected request: number = 0;
    protected ipc : IpcRenderer;
    constructor( protected http: HttpClient ) {
        if ( ( <any>window ).require ) {
            try {
                this.ipc = ( <any>window ).require( "electron" ).ipcRenderer;
            } catch ( error ) {
                throw error;
            }
        } else {
            console.warn( "Could not load electron ipc" );
        }
    }
    
    getDataTable( dataTablesParameters : any) : Observable<any[]>{
        var id = this.request;
        this.request += 1;
        this.ipc.send( "getData" , id, dataTablesParameters);
        return new Observable<any[]>(observer => {
            this.ipc.once( "getData-" + id, ( event, arg ) => {
                dataTablesParameters.recordsTotal= arg.recordsTotal;
                dataTablesParameters.recordsFiltered=arg.recordsFiltered;
                observer.next(arg.data);
            });
        });
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you add a simple example where this behaviour happens? I strongly suspect that ChangeDetection is not triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using NgZone and ChangeDetectorRef: probably the call was made inside the MatTable component and the changes in subscription were not rendered in the main component.

In the main component:

```
refreshTable(event?:any){
        ...
        this.dataSource.loadData(this.dtOptions).then(()=>this.cd.markForCheck());
    }
```

The loadData of the dataSource now have to return a Promise in order to trigger the markForCheck after the loading

```
loadData(request : any) : Promise<void> {
return new Promise(resolve, reject )=>{...})
}
```

And for what concern the dialog, it's in NgZone.run

```
this.zone.run(()=>{this.dialog.open(...)}));
```

Thanks to @gsa.interactive for the ChangeDetectorRef hint

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar, by using material components which get their values from an Input() value. Need to use the ChangeDetectorRef on ngOnChanges or ngAfterContentInit.

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() data: string[];

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

You may need to change the strategy to push:

```
@Component({
...
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
...
})
```

Comment: Using `detectChanges` inside `ngOnChanges` is something you absolutely **don't** want to do. And using a more restrictive `ChangeDetectionStrategy` like `onPush` is indeed preferrable (performance-wise) but will not help solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I think the problem come from the data table and not the dialog itself